# (SVG) File Association in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, file-association

After I upgrade the Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10, nautilus is not associating .svg files with inkscape anymore (its mimetype is **image/svg+xml**). The **Open With** list does not have inkscape there. The same happens with **Other application...** inside the Open With menu. I also cannot add the inkscape there. There is no way to add inkscape manually by right click on an icon.

The default association is the **Image Viewer** which is ok, but I want the inkscape the **Open With** list. Someone knows how to add inkscape on that list?

Using **Nautilus 3.14.2**.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the mimetype of an SVG file. `mimetype your.svg`

Comment: And the output of `cat /usr/share/applications/inkscape.desktop`

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem after I remove the **inkscape.desktop** from **~/.local/share/applications/**. But I don't know how the launcher goes there after the upgrade and how it was hiding inkscape of "Open With" list.